# Questions about a flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to generate a flow chart like this using TikZ package.

[image]

Below is my code but I could not complete the following:

1. How can I connect the question mark to 1st column of "yes/no" boxes　using lines?
2. How can I put numbers (1,2,3,4) on the lines to denote 4 different scenarios?
3. How can I connect 2nd column of "yes/no" boxes to 3rd column of boxes (CO, D, NT, AT) using arrows?
4. Any possible ways put a large box or some highlighted areas for 1st columns and 2nd columns of "Yes/No" boxes to denote that there are two different phases (Phase 1 and Phase 2)?

Any suggestion on improving the coding and the flow chart will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\RequirePackage{epstopdf}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\tikzstyle{circle} = [draw, ellipse,fill=pink!20, node distance=3.3cm, minimum height=2.5em, text width=3.5em, text centered]

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=3.4em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1.5em, node distance=3.3cm]

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, -latex']



\node [block] (Rone) {\small{Yes}};
\node [block, below of=Rone,below=-2.8cm] (Rtwo) {\small{No1}};

\node [block, right of=Rone,right=-1.5cm] (Tone) {\small{Yes1}};
\node [block, right of=Rtwo,right=-1.5cm] (Ttwo) {\small{No1}};

\node [block, below of=Rtwo,below=-2.5cm] (Rthree) {\small{Yes2}};
\node [block, below of=Rthree,below=-2.8cm] (Rfour) {\small{No2}};

\node [block, right of=Rthree,right=-1.5cm] (Tthree) {\small{Yes2}};
\node [block, right of=Rfour,right=-1.5cm] (Tfour) {\small{Yes2}};

\node [block, below of=Rfour,below=-2.5cm] (Rfive) {\small{Yes3}};
\node [block, below of=Rfive,below=-2.8cm] (Rsix) {\small{No3}};

\node [block, right of=Rfive,right=-1.5cm] (Tfive) {\small{No3}};
\node [block, right of=Rsix,right=-1.5cm] (Tsix) {\small{No3}};

\node [block, below of=Rsix,below=-2.5cm] (Rseven) {\small{Yes4}};
\node [block, below of=Rseven,below=-2.8cm] (Reight) {\small{No4}};

\node [block, right of=Rseven,right=-1.5cm] (Tseven) {\small{No4}};
\node [block, right of=Reight,right=-1.5cm] (Teight) {\small{Yes4}};

\node [circle,  below left =0.1 cm and 2 cm of Rfour] (Pat) {\large{?}};

\node [circle,  below right =-0.2 cm and 2 cm of Tone] (C) {\scriptsize{CO}};

\node [circle,  below right =-0.4 cm and 2 cm of Tthree] (C) {\scriptsize{AT}};

\node [circle,  below right =-0.4 cm and 2 cm of Tfive] (C) {\scriptsize{NT}};

\node [circle,  below right =-0.2 cm and 2 cm of Tseven] (C) {\scriptsize{DF}};


\path [line] (Rone) -- (Tone);
\path [line] (Rtwo) -- (Ttwo);
\path [line] (Rthree) -- (Tthree);
\path [line] (Rfour) -- (Tfour);
\path [line] (Rfive) -- (Tfive);
\path [line] (Rsix) -- (Tsix);
\path [line] (Rseven) -- (Tseven);
\path [line] (Reight) -- (Teight);


\draw [-] (Tone.east) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Ttwo.east);
\draw [-] (Tthree.east) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Tfour.east);
\draw [-] (Tfive.east) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Tsix.east);
\draw [-] (Tseven.east) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Teight.east);

\draw [-] (Rone.west) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Rtwo.west);
\draw [-] (Rthree.west) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Rfour.west);
\draw [-] (Rfive.west) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Rsix.west);
\draw [-] (Rseven.west) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-0.8) -- (Reight.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a follow-up/added MWE to [Help with a flow chart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222776/help-with-a-flow-chart).

Comment: Next time, please note that you can edit your original post e.g. to add code. And that will bring your question back to to top of the 'active' list of questions on the front page. But it saves people having to deal with duplicates, so it keeps things tidy ;).

Comment: About the question: have you considered structuring it as a tree growing east? There are several packages for this, in addition to some built in to TiKZ already. (`trees` library, `qtree`, `tikz-qtree`, `forest` etc. `forest` is generally the most powerful and flexible but the `trees` library is probably a good place to start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a possible solution with three `matrix` nodes and two `\foreach` loops.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily, >=latex
]

\matrix (phase1) [matrix of nodes, 
      nodes={draw, minimum width=1cm, 
             minimum height=5mm, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt}, 
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, fill=yellow!30, label=below:Phase I]
{
Yes \\ No \\[5mm] 
Yes \\ No \\[5mm] 
Yes \\ No \\[5mm] 
Yes \\ No \\
};

\matrix (phase2) [matrix of nodes, 
      nodes={draw, minimum width=1cm, 
             minimum height=5mm, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt}, 
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, right=of phase1, fill=green!30, label=below:Phase II]
{
Yes \\ No \\[5mm] 
No \\ Yes \\[5mm] 
No \\ No \\[5mm] 
Yes \\ Yes \\
};

\matrix (phase3) [matrix of nodes, 
      nodes={draw, minimum width=1cm, 
             minimum height=10mm-\pgflinewidth, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt}, 
      row sep=5mm, right= of phase2]
{
CO \\ 
D \\ 
NT \\ 
AT \\ 
};

\node[circle, draw=green!70!black, fill=green!70, minimum width=1cm,
      anchor=center,left=of phase1] (question) {?};

\foreach \i [count=\x] in {1,3,5,7}{
    \draw[->] (question) --++(.75,0) |- 
               node[above,pos=.75] {\x} (phase1-\i-1.south west);
    \draw[->] (phase2-\i-1.south east) -- (phase3-\x-1);
 }

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
    \draw[->] (phase1-\i-1) -- (phase2-\i-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, this is a really neat solution! I need to learn this matrix thing